# What's the best way to cite the source of a photo?

Tags: discussion, citations

[My recent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/270809/revisions) included a photo for illustration.  I had done like I always (try do) do and added a citation under the photo.

However, an edit was made that moved the citation into the photo's alt-text. This made the citation invisible to a casual viewer, although if you were scraping the page it would be in the output.

What's the preferred way to cite the source of a photo?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The alt text, or formally [alt attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute), is meant for a short description of the image, to be used when the image cannot be displayed, typically used by screen readers for visually impaired users.

A source citation is not an adequate description of the image and as such should not be put in the alt text, but rather as a separate line underneath the image.